# TelephonyManager.getDeviceId only returns 14 digit

Tags: android

`TelephonyManager.getDeiceId()` only return 14 digits of IMEI number. 
But under Setting->Phone->Status show 15 digits.

I want to get 15 digit as appear under phone settings.

Comment: what have you tried ?  android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() ???

Comment: yes I tried only TelephonyManager.getDeiceId()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IMEI (14 digits) is complemented by a check digit. The check digit is not 
part of the digits transmitted at IMEI check occasions. The Check Digit shall 
avoid manual transmission errors, e.g. when customers register stolen mobiles 
at the operator's customer care desk.

http://www.tele-servizi.com/Janus/texts/imei.txt

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity

Comment: How to get or calculate the check digit?

Comment: Seriously? Will I have to read the link for you? lol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity#Check_digit_computation

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
 mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId()
```

This is what i have done and i getting all the 15 digits may this can help u ...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can manually calculate the check-sum of the 14-digit IMEI number. e.g.

```
private int GetCheckSumDigit(String id) {
        int digit = -1;
        try{
            if(id.length() == 14)
            {
                String str = "";
                char[] digits = new char[id.length()];
                id.getChars(0, id.length(), digits, 0);
                for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++)
                {
                    String ch = digits[i]+"";
                    if((i+1)%2==0)
                    {
                        int x = Integer.parseInt(digits[i]+"");
                        x *= 2;
                        ch = x+"";
                    }
                    str += ch;
                }
                digits = new char[str.length()];
                str.getChars(0, str.length(), digits, 0);
                int total = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
                    total += Integer.parseInt(digits[i]+"");
                //
                int count = 0;
                while((total+count)%10 != 0)
                    count++;
                digit = count;
            }
        }catch(Exception exx)
        {
            exx.printStackTrace();
        }
        return digit;
    }
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices don't add last digit, we need to calculate last digit instead using [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm):

```
private int getImeiCheckDigit(String imei14digits) {
    if (imei14digits == null || imei14digits.length() != 14) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("IMEI should be 14 digits");
    }
    int[] imeiArray = new int[imei14digits.length()];
    final int DIVIDER = 10;
    char[] chars = imei14digits.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        imeiArray[i] = Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < imeiArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum += imeiArray[i];
        } else {
            int multi = imeiArray[i] * 2;
            if (multi >= DIVIDER) {
                sum += multi % DIVIDER;
                sum += multi / DIVIDER;
            } else {
                sum += multi;
            }
        }
    }
    return (DIVIDER - sum % DIVIDER) % DIVIDER;
}
```

Comment: I ported this function to c# and It is working, I am going to look into this Luhn Algorithm thank you for your post!